# Make a loop to display a blank form or pre-filled form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I wish I could make a loop to display a blank form when I're no answers in my database.

For the moment I have this code :

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      {% for question in questions %}<hr>

    <label for="question">{{ question }} [{{ question.id }}]</label>  
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>

  </p>

  {% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
    </p>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
 </table>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="../../baseVisite/" class="btn btn-success">Retour</a></center>
  </form>
```

This form allows me to change the answers to the questions but if there already has answers in my database ...
I would then make a loop to display blank forms if there are no answers yet

**How can I do this loop?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`for...empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) template tag for this.

```
{% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
    <p>
        <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
        <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
    </p>
{% empty %}

    {# your blank form goes here #}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `empty` is good but the problem is that when it shows me the blank fields it didn't save .. Have you any idea why? Should I change forloop.counter?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. Could you update the question with this query?

Comment: It's okay now thanks you very much for your helps ! It's work !

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if question.reply_set.all %}
{% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
<p>
  <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
  <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>
  <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
  <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id"/>
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Basically it checks if there are any answers, if they are it shows them, if there aren't it shows an empty answer form.

Comment: Thank you too for your reply !